# Convert lead com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException error

Tags: soap-api, sandbox, lead-conversion, partner

I have been using SOAP API(v43.0) and patner wsdl(v43.0) for converting leads. It was working fine till sometime. But recently it started failing with com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException. And this is happening for only sandbox env and after spring 21 release. It looks like salesforce added new field `relatedPersonAccountId` to convert lead API response in spring 21 release, which soap API i am using is not able to parse this response becasue of this new field. But when changing the partner wsdl version to v51.0 it is working fine.

why convert lead API response is giving new additional field(`relatedPersonAccountId`) even i am using old version(v43.0) of SOAP API ?

Exception Stack

com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...rtunityId xsi:nil="true"/>... @1:599
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.consumeEndTag(TypeMapper.java:437) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.soap.partner.LeadConvertResult.load(LeadConvertResult.java:238) ~[force-partner-api-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:674) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readArray(TypeMapper.java:580) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:558) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.soap.partner.ConvertLeadResponse_element.setResult(ConvertLeadResponse_element.java:48) ~[force-partner-api-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.soap.partner.ConvertLeadResponse_element.loadFields1(ConvertLeadResponse_element.java:107) ~[force-partner-api-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.soap.partner.ConvertLeadResponse_element.loadFields(ConvertLeadResponse_element.java:83) ~[force-partner-api-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.soap.partner.ConvertLeadResponse_element.load(ConvertLeadResponse_element.java:77) ~[force-partner-api-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:674) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:556) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.bind(SoapConnection.java:180) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:154) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:99) ~[force-wsc-43.0.0.jar:?]
at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.convertLead(PartnerConnection.java:749) ~[force-partner-api-43.0.0.jar:?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed by Salesforce Spring 21 Release Patch 7.2 as written in the known issue.

Ref: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Salesforce-Connector-Convert-Lead-Operation-issue-with-relatedPersonAccountId-Property